# php bin/magento setup:di:compile Fatal Error

Tags: php, magento, dependency-injection, composer-php, magento2

For a while now I have been trying to find a fix for my Magento admin panel, when I want to change some settings it dosent allow me to change anything, for example, "Use system value" boxes are locked and when I hover over them I get a red circle indicating I am unable to change the value.

I found this tutorial: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Unlock-configuration/m-p/95209#M5084

But when I try to run setup:di:compile, I get this error:

"Application code generator... 3/9 [=========>------------------]  33% 5 secs 246.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, bool given in /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php:95
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php(95): rtrim()
#1 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php(286): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Scanner\PhpScanner->getSourceClassName()
#2 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php(152): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Scanner\PhpScanner->shouldGenerateClass()
#3 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php(184): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Scanner\PhpScanner->_fetchMissingExtensionAttributesClasses()
#4 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/ApplicationCodeGenerator.php(77): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Scanner\PhpScanner->collectEntities()
#5 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\T in /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php on line 95

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, bool given in /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php:95
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php(95): rtrim()
#1 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php(286): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Scanner\PhpScanner->getSourceClassName()
#2 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php(152): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Scanner\PhpScanner->shouldGenerateClass()
#3 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php(184): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Scanner\PhpScanner->_fetchMissingExtensionAttributesClasses()
#4 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/ApplicationCodeGenerator.php(77): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Scanner\PhpScanner->collectEntities()
#5 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\T in /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Scanner/PhpScanner.php on line 95"

I have tried composer install and update, but that didn't seem to help...

My php version is 7.4.20.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to Composer? Why not debug the code to see where this is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue after upgrading to Magento2.4.2-p1. I did some analysis on this and got the reason for this error.
Actually, Magento installed some new modules like Magento_TestModuleAsyncAmqp, Magento_TestModuleExtensionAttributes etc.
When you go to file

> app/code/Magento/TestModuleExtensionAttributes/Api/Data/FakeExtensibleTwoInterface.php

you will see

```
/**
     * test incorrect return type
     *
     * **@return int**
     */
    public function getExtensionAttributes();
```

So, here it is asking to provide class as return type instead of `@return int`
If you will add below class as return type then it should work.

> \Magento\TestModuleExtensionAttributes\Api\Data\FakeExtensibleTwoExtensionInterface|int

Try to provide class here and then run di:compile again after clearing cache, generation etc

Answer (score 0):

I came across this and turned out to be an issue when you run integration tests at some point before running `bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Integration tests generate some test modules in `app/code/Magento` which are then picked up by the `setup:di:compile` command.
[image]
I fixed this by removing the `Magento` folder from `app/code`.